# The replace function doesn't work for multi-replace

Tags: php

I have to change in a text file 6 different lines with 6 different words but the function `str_replace` doesn't work. Why?

```
                    $prendo_link_per_replace = "ex.txt";                
                    $uno = "1";
                    $due = "2";
                    $tre = "3";
                    $quattro = "4";
                    $cinque = "5";
                    $sei = "6";
                    $testofile = file_get_contents($prendo_link_per_replace);
                    $testofile = str_replace($uno, $due, $testofile);
                    $testofile = str_replace($due, $tre, $testofile);
                    $testofile = str_replace($tre, $quattro, $testofile);
                    $testofile = str_replace($quattro, $cinque, $testofile);
                    file_put_contents($prendo_link_per_replace, $testofile);
```

I have 2 files:

- `check.php`
- `text.txt`

in `text.php` there's:

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6

The previous code, that I have posted, will replace the number 1,2,3,4 with the next number (2,3,4,5) but the output is only 5 for all lines. I have tried with a loop or fflush() or fwrite() or unset() but the output doesn't change.
After run the code, my page `text.txt` change into:

> 5
> 5
> 5
> 5
> 5
> 6

Why? Any suggestions?
I'm in a Amazon Linux Ami 2 but everywhere doesn't work.

The true problem is that I cannot do more than one `str_replace`. How can I fix?

Comment: Could you please add the `for` cycle and the values of `$ris_9`?

Comment: i have posted a simple example of my problem. Is the same, can you help me? it didn't work.

Comment: so, how can i solve? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your input file:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4

You could try to replace in the opposite order, *e.g.*:

```
$file_name = "ex.txt";
$file_content = file_get_contents($file_name);
$one = "1";
$two = "2";
$three = "3";
$four = "4";
$five = "5";
$file_content = str_replace($four, $five, $file_content);
$file_content = str_replace($three, $four, $file_content);
$file_content = str_replace($two, $three, $file_content);
$file_content = str_replace($one, $two, $file_content);
file_put_contents($file_name, $file_content);
```

Your output file will be:

> 2
>   3
>   4
>   5

Comment: it doesn't work. this code does nothing if you run it.

Comment: @FounderOnepiecepower The code is correct and working. Use your normal debugging techniques to check for errors in your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) which has a **Replacement order gotcha** note on the page, you could alternatively use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).  You can see in the code I've built all of the translations into an array so they are all done at the same time, this also gets round the problem of the content mutating depending on the order of the replacements.

```
$uno = "1";
$due = "2";
$tre = "3";
$quattro = "4";
$cinque = "5";
$sei = "6";
$testofile = file_get_contents($prendo_link_per_replace);
$trans = [$uno => $due, $due => $tre, $tre => $quattro, $quattro =>$cinque ];
$testofile = strtr($testofile, $trans );
file_put_contents($prendo_link_per_replace, $testofile);
```